# SQLAlchemy Model.query.get use generic function to get latest id

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Consider this snippet. I am trying to get the user with the latest id like this:

```py
User.query.get(func.max(User.id))
```

It throws an error saying `Boolean value of this clause is not defined`

How do I get the user with the largest id by using the model.query API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve it like:

```
last_user = User.query.order_by(User.id.desc()).first()
```

An alternative would be:

```
last_user = User.query.filter(
    User.id == select(func.max(User.id)).scalar_subquery()
)
```